# How to transfer magento without cpanel or ftp?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, transfer

There is currently a project I am working on that requires me to transfer a magento site to another server and also update the functions, features and design of the site.  But there are problems with this project.

1)  The company that was hired to create the current magento site has a contract that will not allow my client to access the cpanel or ftp of the site.

2)  My client is only allowed to access the admin of magento.

3)  There are currently over 1700 products and variants in the current site.

4)  There are custom functions and extensions made for this website that needs to be copied and transferred to the new server.

==================================================

Does anyone have any idea what to do?  Because I certainly don't.

==================================================

I checked and I can probably install extensions in the site.  So I am going with "can anyone suggest an extension to work around this problem (a free one would be nice)".  I want to try this http://hipglossconnect.com/magento-file-manager-extension/  but I have not tested it yet.

Comment: Well I had to do it the hard way.  Took me about 3 months to copy everything from the other site manually.  Thanks for the answers but I couldn't find a solution because if I installed an extension the site would break and there was nothing more I could do there.

Answer (score 3):

There's no other way. FTP is probably the minimum to get a Magento website transfered because you can execute a full backup in the admin and restore the file system and database. Even with CPanel access, using phpmyadmin is not recommended for Magento because of the database size.
The host holding their Magento site almost sounds illegal unless they made it clear during sign up that they will not allow those access levels.

Note to your client: Keep in mind, businesses have a reputation to uphold *Hint* * Hint*

Answer (score 3):

You cant transfer magento without FTP or Cpanel access. Cpanel access is good because you can do transfer easily and fast as compare to FTP where you will have to download and upload.

One another thing you can do to request compressed copy of files and database. They can provide you direct link to download these files which you can uncompress  on new host and setup site there. In this method you dont need access of ftp/cpanel.

This is common problem and clients are not technical and fear to give access of cpanel so you can request them for use above method.

SSH access is best one that transfer site in few moments but thats also not possible in your case. If you have SSH access of DESTINATION host then you can do quite fast.

Comment: The company that host and made the site has hacked versions of payed extensions.  That was why they did not want me or anyone to copy their code, files and database.  I managed to finish the site but had to do the encoding for the products one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access to the host you can dump the database, Tarball the file system, download everything and then re-upload to the new host.